# Tangent Normal Bake artifacts

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map, artifacts

I am expecting a solid color bake at (0.5,0.5,1) but I am getting a bake as if it is the difference of the split normals and the original. Does anyone know the cause to avoid the streak artifacts on the tangent normal map bake?

Here's a screenshot from the attached blend file showing matcap shading, baked normal map, shader, setup, and bake settings.
[image]

[image]